# Let $A \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ with $\operatorname{rank} (I_n + A) + \operatorname{rank} (I_n − A) = n$. Show that $A^2 = I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $$\operatorname{rank} (I_n + A) + \operatorname{rank} (I_n − A) = n$$ Show that $A^2 = I_n$. Hint: Use the Jordan canonical form of $A$.

---

If I were to use the Jordan canonical form of $A$, am I supposed to show conjugation between the two ranks while assuming that there exists an invertible square matrix?

I'm having trouble understanding the connection between the ranks, identity matrix and the squaring the matrix itself.

Comment: Forget about the Jordan form. The condition yields that the dimensions of the subspaces $\ker\left(I_n+A\right)$ and $\ker\left(I_n-A\right)$ sum up to $n$. But these two subspaces clearly have intersection $0$. What does this mean for the sum of these two subspaces?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on darij grinberg's comment:

**Proposition.** Let $F$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}(F)\not= 2$ and $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix over $F$. If $\operatorname{rank}(I_n + A)+\operatorname{rank}(I_n − A) = n$, then $A^2=I_n.$

*Proof.* By the dimension formula we have
$$n-\dim \ker (I_n+A)+n-\dim \ker (I_n-A)=n,$$
so $\dim \ker (I_n+A)+\dim \ker (I_n-A)=n.$

It is easy to verify $\ker (I_n+A)\cap\ker (I_n-A)=\{0\}$, hence $\dim (\ker (I_n+A)+\ker (I_n-A))=n $:
$$v\in\ker (I_n+A)\cap\ker (I_n-A)\implies v=-Av=Av\implies2v=0\implies v=0.$$
The last implication uses $\operatorname{char}(F)\not= 2$.

Since $I_n-A^2=(I_n+A)(I_n-A)=(I_n-A)(I_n+A)$, $\ker (I_n+A)$ and $\ker (I_n-A)$ are subspaces of $\ker (I_n-A^2)$. Therefore $\ker (I_n+A)+\ker (I_n-A) \subset\ker (I_n-A^2)$. In consequence, $\dim\ker (I_n-A^2)=n$. Another application of the dimension formula yields $\operatorname{rank}(I_n-A^2)=0$, so $A^2=I_n$. $\square$

The characteristic condition $\operatorname{char}(F)\not= 2$ is necessary:

**Example.** Let
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \in M_{2} \ (\mathbb{Z} /2\mathbb{Z}) \ ,$$
then $\operatorname{rank}(I_2 + A)+\operatorname{rank}(I_2 − A) = 2$, but $A^2\not = I_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$. Note that:

- $J + \alpha I$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A + \alpha I$ for any $\alpha$
- $A^2 = I$ if and only if $J^2 = I$
- $-J$ is similar to $-A$
- $A$ and $J$ have the same rank
- $I + A$ and $I + J$ have the same rank
- $I - A$ and $I - J$ have the same rank

So, it's enough to show that if $J$ is a matrix in Jordan canonical form, then
$$
\operatorname{rank}(I + J) + 
\operatorname{rank}(I - J) = n
$$
Now, which Jordan block matrices satisfy $J^2 = I$?